# Using Google Analytics on a 503 page

Tags: apache, google-analytics, varnish, http-status-code-503

I'm using varnish to cache our pages.  When we get a 503 -- which happens a little too often -- I'd like to put some sort of page tracking on there.  I'd like to place the GA code in there.  I can't seem to find any instance of anyone else doing this.  Has anyone done this?  Is there some sort of T&C violation in doing this?

Comment: When you get a 503 page does the user get redirected to a different page or does he see the same page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Varnish you can use **vcl_error** to include your own responses (that have the Google Analytics code).

*Edit: I have not tested any of these. They are just examples.*

An example:

```
sub vcl_error {
    set obj.http.Content-Type = "text/html; charset=utf-8";

    if (obj.status == 503) {
        synthetic {"
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Error</h1>
<p>Something</p>
<!-- ANALYTICS CODE -->
</body>
</html>
        "};

        return(deliver);
    }
}
```

Alternatively you can add your own pages from the file system by using [vmod](https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/3.0/reference/vmod_std.html) (which is included as standard with version 3.*+).

```
# Add this to the top of your config
import std;

# vcl_error
sub vcl_error {
    set obj.http.Content-Type = "text/html; charset=utf-8";

    if (obj.status == 503) {
        set obj.http.error503 = std.fileread("/path/to/errors/503.html");
        synthetic obj.http.error503;
        return(deliver);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can just do "synthetic std.fileread("/path/to/errors/503.html");" instead.